# Django Http response/Json Response?

Tags: django, flask, httpresponse, jsonresponse

I need help getting my receipt printer working with post/get commands.
Here is the code in django/python. It runs without any error message, but it's not printing anything

```
import requests
import json
from email import header
import mimetypes
import urllib.request
from urllib import response
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.http import JsonResponse
content = "some content"

if request.method == "POST":
    data = {"jobReady": "true", "mediaTypes":["text/plain"]}
    return JsonResponse(data)

if request.method == "GET":
    data = open("print.txt","r") 

    response_r = {
        'response':data,
        'status':200,
        'mimetype':'text/plain'
    }
    return HttpResponse(response_r)
    
if request.method == "DELETE":
    status_code = request.GET['code']

    if (status_code == "200 OK"):
        print("Success")
        return HttpResponse(status=200)

    if (status_code == "211 OK Paper Low"):
        print("Success, Paper Low")
        return HttpResponse(status=200)
```

Here's the code in flask. It's working and printing properly, but I want to rewrite it in Django.

```
from email import header
import mimetypes
from urllib import response
import urllib.request
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, Response, make_response

app = Flask(__name__)

#flask --app CloudPRNTDemo run -h 192.168.1.218 -p 8000
@app.route('/')
def home():
    yes = ("home page")
    return(yes)

@app.route('/print/', methods=['POST', 'GET', 'DELETE'])
def cloudPRNTPOST():
    if request.method == "POST":
        data = {"jobReady": "true", "mediaTypes":["text/plain"]}
        print(data)
        return jsonify(data)

    if request.method == "GET":
        data = open("print.txt","r")        
        response_r = app.response_class(
            response=data,
            status=200,
            mimetype='text/plain'
        )
        # response.headers['X-Star-Buzzerendpattern'] = 1
        return response_r
    if request.method == "DELETE":
        status_code = request.args.get('code')
        print(status_code)

        if (status_code == "200 OK"):
            print("Success")
            return app.response_class(status=200)

        if (status_code == "211 OK Paper Low"):
            print("Success, Paper Low")
            return app.response_class(status=200)

    return 
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8000, debug = True)
```

Can someone translate the code from flask to django?

Comment: what have you done so far to setup a basic django project structure? you need urlpattern in urls.py and your code in a view function in views.py

Comment: This is basically one function in views.py. The rest of the stuff like urls.py, settings, etc aren't relevant. This specific function is not a webpage, it listens and sends post/get/delete commands to/from the receipt printer. When the receipt printer receives a GET command from python, it prints out a receipt with the contents specified in the variable "data".